# ViewController has no segue, swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

This is a very popular question but with all the two days I have spent hunting a solution, nothing has worked.

I have two TableView Controllers (WeekTableViewController and DiscoverTableViewController) as shown in the picture linked by the segue shown with the name "discoverWorkouts". The DiscoverTableViewController is a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController.

[image]

[image]

On adding the usual function to segue from the WeekTableViewController to the DiscoverTableViewController, I get the following nasty Error: 
"WeekTableViewController: 0x1058469c0>) has no segue with identifier 'discoverWorkouts''

I have a button created programatically in the WeekTableViewController and this is my code.

WeekTableViewController :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //transitionManager = TransitionManager(transitionAnimation: .Fade)
        //transitioningDelegate = transitionManager


        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true //Hide the navigation bar
        //        tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
        //        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true


        //Add a button to the
        pingbutton   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        pingbutton.frame = CGRectMake(328, 620, 30,  30)
        pingbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "discover"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        pingbutton.addTarget(self, action: "pingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        pingbutton.hidden = true

        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(ping button)


....

}

//MARK: Button Tapped
    func pingButtonTapped(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("discoverWorkouts", sender:self)
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "openDiscover" {

            let discoveryView = segue.destinationViewController as! DiscoverTableViewController
            discoveryView.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
        }

    }
```

Putting a break point on the "self.performSegueWithIdentifier("discoverWorkouts", sender:self)" shows that's where the error occurs.

I have tried everything from:

- Deleting the app on my device and installing it again.
- Deleting the Segue and adding it again with different names.
- Rebuilding both tableViewControllers and placing the segue again.

Nothing has worked at all.

Also in my app delegate this is how the WeekTableViewController is launched:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        //Launch Process
            let weekView =  WeekTableViewController()
            self.landingNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: weekView)
            self.landingNavigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            self.landingNavigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

            self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor() //(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.landingNavigationController
//            self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarNavController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


}
```

Any ideas on what in the world could be happening. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate your `ViewController`s from your storyboard, if you want to use the features of it.

So instead of creating your `ViewController`s yourself, you should do something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
self.landingNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
// additional setup (optional)
self.window?.rootViewController = self.landingNavigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This will create your initial `ViewController` (probably a `UINavigationController`) as it's configured in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It worked with a slight tweek. I realised my WeekTableViewController didn't have a Navigation Controller so I embedded one to it and with your suggestion it all worked out. ;).